# Class Library (.NET Standard) Template Not working in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2019, .net-standard-2.0

After Installing Visual Studio 2019 Community, I tried to make Class Library (.NET Standard).  Immediately afterwards, I got the errors in the output:

[image]

It seems like the dependencies are not mapping correctly.  Any ideas?

Comment: have you tried rebuilding/

Comment: Yes.  I deleted the project and repeated the same steps.  I get the same set of errors.

Comment: Does it have the .net standard nuget, have you tried to restore it. Are you using resharper? What version of standard is this?. are you on the latest version VS. Anyway this is likely a bug with vs community and the template.

Comment: I pointed to the .NET Standard in the NuGet Administrator and it installed.  Out of the box I had assumed it didn't need to do that.  I am new to NuGet.  under the Installed packages in the manager, I see it appears as installed, however, Uninstall and update buttons in the right pane are disabled.

Comment: I was following the class library example in the following link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tutorials/library-with-visual-studio

Comment: Its hard to help you here, as this should just work. If you create a .net standard 2.1 project, does it work?

Comment: I think it is the NuGet Package Manager configuration that might be the issue.  After the install, I only had Visual Studio Offline Packages, which did not contain the NET Standard library.  I had to manually add NuGet.org to the configuration in order to install that package.  Not sure if where I am pointing is actually correct.  It's pointing to http://packages.nuget.org/v1/FeedService.svc

Comment: it should be `https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

Comment: I did find https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json and added that as well.  Shouldn't you be able to un-install a package.  For me the uninstall and update are both disabled.  Not sure why.

Comment: delete obj folder with **project.assets.json** and **csproj.nuget.** files

Answer (score 0):

After completely uninstalling and reinstalling Visual Studio 2019, the issue has now been resolved.  This time, the NET Standard Library template had no problem building and had no issues being referred to by a .NET Core project in the solution.  As per TheGeneral, this time, it just worked.